# New to ML: ValueError Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? I have just finished the first ML course in Kaggle and it's my first time doing a solo with a football dataset. I got stuck with this error:

> **ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [66, 23]**

This is my code (apologies if code is a bit awkward - I am very new)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# House cleaning
winners_hist_path = '../input/spanish-football-la-liga-champions/La_Liga_Winners.csv'
winners_hist = pd.read_csv(winners_hist_path)

# Data fixing
winners_hist['season_new'] = winners_hist['Season'].apply(lambda d: d[:2] + d[-2:])
winners_hist = winners_hist.drop(['Season'], axis=1)
winners_hist = winners_hist.drop([8, 9, 10])
winners_hist = winners_hist.reset_index()
winners_hist = winners_hist.rename(columns={"Goals": "goals"})


# Creating instance of labelencoder
labelencoder = LabelEncoder()

# Assigning numerical values and storing in another column
winners_hist['first_le'] = labelencoder.fit_transform(winners_hist['Winner'])
winners_hist['second_le'] = labelencoder.fit_transform(winners_hist['Runner-up'])
winners_hist['third_le'] = labelencoder.fit_transform(winners_hist['Third Place'])
winners_hist['topscorer_le'] = labelencoder.fit_transform(winners_hist['Top Scorer'])
winners_hist['topscorer_club_le'] = labelencoder.fit_transform(winners_hist['Top scorer\'s club(s)'])


# Create new DataFrame
winners_hist = winners_hist.drop(['index', 'Winner', 'Runner-up', 'Third Place', 'Top Scorer', 'Top scorer\'s club(s)'], axis=1)
winners_hist = winners_hist[['season_new', 'first_le', 'second_le', 'third_le', 'topscorer_le', 'topscorer_club_le', 'goals']]

# Select features
features = ['season_new', 'second_le', 'third_le', 'topscorer_le', 'topscorer_club_le', 'goals']
y = winners_hist.first_le
X = winners_hist[features]

# Split data
train_X, train_y, val_X, val_y = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=1)

# Specify model
laliga_model = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=1)

# Fit model
laliga_model.fit(train_X, train_y)
```

Here's a sample of the data set:

```
season_new  first_le    second_le   third_le    topscorer_le    topscorer_club_le   goals
0   1929    3           7           1           38              17                  14
1   1930    0           3           0           19              0                   19
2   1931    0           6           13          0               0                   27
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably `X` and `y` have diffrent shapes, check:

```
X.shape[0]

y.shape[0]
```

Method `train_test_split` requires it to be equal.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Both X and y are 89. I also did print(X.shape)
print(y.shape) and this came out (89, 6) (89,)

Comment: Can You locate what exactly fragment of code causes an error?